# ReSharper Ultimate error "There're inconsistent modifications to the file..."

Tags: c#, visual-studio, resharper

Using ReSharper Ultimate, and it seems to have have gotten into a really weird state regarding file consistency. I try to rename a method, and I get this error:

> There're inconsistent modifications to the file
>   C:\Users\Me\src\iQue\Code\iQue\CommandHandler.cs

And yet the refactoring is performed successfully. But I am left in doubt as to the tool's trustworthyness at this point.

I've tried the following:

- Restarting visual studio
- Restarting
- Removing the cache through ReSharper | Options | General | Clear caches
- Removing the .vs folder
- Removing the cache by manually deleting the contents of C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Transient\ReSharperPlatformVs15\v11_e67f2b15
- Changing to a git commit from before this started happening
- Changing the directory's name

Has anyone seen this nonsense before?

Edit: Upgraded from Re#: 2017.3.2 to 2018.1.4. No dice.

Comment: Which version of ReSharper? 2018.1.4? And which version of Visual Studio?

Comment: VS Enterprise 2017: 15.7.5, Re#: 2017.3.2. Looks like there's a new version of the latter. I'll give that a try. Probably won't make it worse.

Comment: Did you find the cause of the issue? I just updated to the latest version 2019.2 and I am having the same problem now

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same issue using inspectcode.exe in my build. If I go and manually clear the cache in SolutionCache folder I can get clean logs. My build plan compiles and analyze warnings using inspectcode.exe and this comes when a solution is getting analyzed in 2 consecutively running builds. If I clear cache both builds are clean.

I can think of setting solution cache in seperate folders for builds by using --cache-home parameter. However, I dont want to replicate 'caches' as it will eat unnecessary space.